# The syntax of mysql_query in php

Tags: php

```
$cek=mysql_query('SELECT Header FROM CompletedHotelProjects LIMIT'.$count.', '.$count+2);
```

When I write this query, it fails. Can you help me, how can I write the right syntax?

Thanks...

Comment: What happens when you try to execute the query? Does it throw an error? What is the expected result? What are you getting instead? Your question lacks all these details. Please learn [how to ask a question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). :)

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: i think you shouldn't  close the single quote after limit, in this case the limit is the end  your query and the numbers are not counted as part of the query.

Comment: Every outdated mysql_ tutorial includes mysql_error(). Every question on StackOverflow regarding mysql_query() and an unknown error suggests mysql_error(). We don't need any more of these questions.

Comment: WARNING: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php do you see the red rectangle? You should not use this function instead use PDO or MySQLi

Comment: Why not go ORM with doctrine?

Comment: at first, thank you for your beneficial answers all guys. Amal Murali, When I write this code, the query does not work. It gives error (!cek)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$cek = mysql_query(
   "SELECT Header FROM CompletedHotelProjects LIMIT ".$count.", ".($count+2).";"
       );
```

Comment: Some programming languages are still a bit dumb. If you don't concatenate a `String` at the end, it may think that the `String` ends on the `", "`, giving you a syntax error.

Comment: @HasanSaitArslan: You should accept the answer by clicking on the green-checkmark if it answers your question! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$cek=mysql_query('SELECT `Header` FROM `CompletedHotelProjects` LIMIT '.$count.', '.$count+2);
```

EDIT:
Maybe by adding the extra braces it will.

```
$cek=mysql_query('SELECT `Header` FROM `CompletedHotelProjects` LIMIT '.$count.', '.($count+2));
```

Always use `` signs to indicate a column or table and added a space between LIMIT and the first number.

Comment: @SnakeEyes Thanks, I forgot to format it properly. I was just finding out it looked weird without it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
$new_count = $count+2;

$cek=mysql_query('SELECT Header FROM CompletedHotelProjects LIMIT $count,$new_count');
```

Comment: @HasanSaitArslan can you tell me what errors you get when you run this query ?

Comment: Thank you Rakesh. Lucas' advice works.

Comment: You will have to use "" double quotes in order for `"echo my $count here"` to work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with below query,

```
$countEnd = $count+2;
$cek=mysql_query('SELECT Header FROM CompletedHotelProjects LIMIT'.$count.', '.$countEnd);
```

i think this will help you to find a way.

Comment: I've tried it already. It still doesn't work.

Comment: what error you got? please post your error, so that we can help on that.

Comment: I think I've managed it. Thank you. Lucas Harada's advice works.